# How to write the expression of norm in Mathematica

Tags: formatting, latex

Please how I can write the following expression of Latex in Mathematica

$\parallel F \parallel_{L^2 (\omega)} $

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ctrl+4 and use the LaTeX code.  `\lVert F \rVert_{L^2(\omega)}`

Comment: `TraditionalForm`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJe0U.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\!\(\(\[DoubleVerticalBar]\)\(F\)
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[DoubleVerticalBar]\), \(
\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(L\), \(2\)]\)[\[Omega]]\)]\)
```

$$\parallel F\parallel _{L^2(\omega )}$$

---

Also,

```
TraditionalForm[Norm[F, (L^2)[\[Omega]]]]
```

$$\| F \| _ {L^2 (\omega)}$$

Comment: I just did that in my comment. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Synchronicity or may be telepathy  :)

Comment: @Syed Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the accept.